# Cannot manage to have heights relative to items contents with css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Currently when I create a css layout with grid, items within this layout will take up the height of the heighest item. Is it possible to make an item take only the height its content needs?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NQpQOr

In this example, I want `div2` to have a height relative to its content.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: `align-self:start`? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `align-self` property to fix it:

```
.div-2 {
  align-self: start;
}
```